Quasi periodic functions on Tours
Let $\mathbb T$ be the fundamental parallelogram for the torus, with vertices on $0,1,i\tau, 1+i\tau$. Is there an analytic function which is quasiperodic in the following sense?
$$f(z+1)=f(z)\qquad f(z+i\tau)=-f(z)$$
I can create such a function with ratios of Jacobi theta functions, but that creates poles. Any reference for this, or does such a function exist?

Such a function would be bounded, no?

Yes, but it's not analytic at the boundary. Something like the Jacobi theta function.
